# 'File.Copy' does not overwrite a file

Tags: c#, .net

Using the following code, I am trying to overwrite a file if it exists. Currenly it throws [IOException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx). How can I fix this problem?

```
File.Copy(filePath, newPath);
```

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Use

```
File.Copy(filePath, newPath, true);
```

The third parameter is overwrite, so if you set it to true the destination file will be overwritten.

See: [File.Copy in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx)

Comment: For "floating bools" I follow the rule to always use them as Named parameters for clarity File.Copy(filePath, newPath, overwrite: true);

Comment: if we use false as that third parameter, what happens... no copy?  Is there a way to still copy the file and rename it?

Comment: @deebs It throws an `IOException` if "`destFileName` exists and `overwrite` is `false`".

Answer (score 20):

There is an overload to this function that contains a third parameter. This parameter is called "overwrite". If you pass `true`, as long as the file is not read-only, it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 12):

Then call [the overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328774%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

```
File.Copy(filePath, newPath, true);
```

Answer (score 7):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx), you can do:

```
File.Copy(filePath, newPath, true);
```

Answer (score 6):

Then use the other [`File.Copy(string, string, boolean)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx). The third parameter indicates whether or not to overwrite the destination file if it exists (`true` if you want overwrite, `false` otherwise).

But what did you expect? If the function is designed to throw when the destination file exists, you need to find a way around that problem. So either:

1. Search the documentation or Intellisense for an overload that does what you are asking.
2. Barring that, create a wrapper around `File.Copy(string, string)` that deletes the destination file for you if it exists.

Answer (score 5):

```
File.Copy(filePath, newPath, bool overwrite)
```

does it.

Answer (score 5):

This can help you:

I use this and it works,

```
File.Copy(src,des,true); //(string source, string destination, bool overwrite)
```

Reference (MSDN): *[File.Copy Method (String, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx)*